# How to loop over an array of arbitrary number of nested arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an array from the backend that has an abritrary number of nested arrays. Each array element is a company and may or may not have a *Children* property which is again an array of companies that each may or may not have child companies. For example:

```
[ 
   { 
      Name:"Company X",
      Children:[ 
         { 
            Name:"Company XY"
         },
         { 
            Name:"Company XZ",
            Children:[ 
               { 
                  Name: "Company XZY"    // third level of nested arrays, can be an abritrary number of levels
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   { 
      Name:"Company Y",
      Children:[ 
         { 
            Name:"Company YZ"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have to add a "Label" property to each company object. The property is equal to the "Name" property.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotta use recursion here.

```
function addLabelRecursive(company) {
  if (company.Name) {
    company.Label = company.Name;
  }
  if (company.Children) {
    company.Children.forEach(addLabelRecursive);
  }
}
```

This function adds a label and if children exist runs itself for each child.

[Working code for your sample data](https://repl.it/repls/RawHoneydewMenus)